# Is atomic deployment possible with Helm subcharts in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Provided I have deployment defined in Helm Chart with **subcharts**.

Does "helm install --atomic ..." rollback the deployment of all charts and subcharts in case any of the chart/subchart deployment fails.

In other words is the whole deployment including subcharts atomic?

Comment: Please elaborate your question. Which helm version are you using? What did you try? Which K8s version are you using? How looks this chart?

Comment: In any version of k8s and any version of helm. "--atomic" says it should be atomic - I am just want to know if it is true also for chart with subcharts (as it is quite some time mentioned in the doc that they are independent)